# apache netbeans 11.1 php new line before endif

Tags: php, formatting, netbeans, braces

I am using netbeans (version : Apache Netbeans IDE 11.1; Netbeans 8.2 Patch 2) to write some php/html code.
I'm using the

> **if : ... endif;**

style.

The **endif** at the end of a php file keeps getting a new line add between it and the preceeding closing braces.

> if (!function_exists('test')):
>
> function test()
>     {
>
> }
>
> endif;

I have "auto format on save" on and every time I save the file the number of new lines grows!
I have tried changing some of the format options but cannot find one to stop tis behaviour.

Please help!

Comment: Please update your question with the version of NetBeans that you are using.

Comment: Of course, should have done that! Apache Netbeans IDE 11.1, Netbeans 8.2 Patch 2